# Export MySQL to CSV, some columns with quotes and some without

Tags: mysql, csv, export-to-csv

I am exporting a MySQL table and I want to export the integer type columns without double quotes but the varchar type columns with double quotes. I need to do this to have the correct formatting for the next step in my work. Can this be done in MySQL? I know I could probably do this in a python script but the csv files are pretty large (>1 GB) so I think it might take awhile to do that. Anyway, is this possible using MySQL Queries?

Here's my current export script format:

```
SELECT 
   'column_name_1',
   'column_name_2',
   ...
   'column_name_n'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table
INTO OUTFILE 'table.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

If it helps, here is the table (more importantly, the types involved) I am trying to export:

```
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| field_1                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| field_2                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| field_3                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| field_4                 | char(1)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| field_5                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| field_6                 | varchar(4)       | NO   |     |         |       |
| field_7                 | char(1)          | NO   |     | Y       |       |
| field_8                 | varchar(20)      | NO   |     |         |       |
| field_9                 | varchar(200)     | NO   |     |         |       |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

EDIT 1: I tried `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` as suggested in an answer, but when I add that to the script, it double quotes every column, not just the string (or varchar) columns. Any idea why it might do this?

Comment: _“it double quotes every column, not just the string (or varchar) columns. Any idea why it might do this?”_ – because why not? It is perfectly ok to just quote _all_ field values, no matter what they contain, and have a “valid” CSV file in the end. Why do you _care_ if there’s quotes around integer values?

Comment: @CBroe *I need to do this to have the correct formatting for the next step in my work.*

Comment: @CBroe Obviously he's not using a general-purpose CSV parser for the next step

Comment: Right, the software that I'm importing these csv files into won't recognize the columns as integers if they have double quotes.

Comment: I need this because my output is going to be a bash script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use the `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
INTO OUTFILE 'table.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

The `OPTIONALLY` modifier makes it do this only for string columns.

You also need to leave out the subquery that returns the header line. The problem is that all rows of a union need to have the same types in the columns, so it's converting all the non-strings to strings to match the header line.

Comment: When I use OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"', it encloses every column with quotes?

Comment: I just tried it myself and the integer columns didn't get quoted. Maybe it's dependent on sql modes or some other setting?

Comment: What version of MySQL? I'm using 5.5.43.

Comment: I see the problem. The first `SELECT` that returns the column names causes all the columns to be treated as strings.

Comment: It's converting the results of the second subquery into strings, because all the rows of a `UNION` have to have the same datatype.

Comment: I see, is there a way to still select the column names but use optionally enclosed by as well?

Comment: I don't think there is. You'll need to insert the header line into the file as a separate step outside MySQL.

Comment: Alright. That's okay at this point since I already have other files with the headers I can copy. Thanks for the help.