# Shows different value after exporting to excel

Tags: mysql

I have table as tab1 in mysql

```
Name       Value
john       22
parker     334
tony       44
;
```

After exporting this table to .csv file the name column shows as

```
Name       Value
"john"     22
"parker"    334
"tony"      44
```

Now how to eliminate those Quotation marks(") from the name column .
Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you export the data? With what tool?

Comment: How are you exporting your data?

Comment: select from table and using icon to export

Answer (score 0):

If you use Phpmyadmin....While exporting table change double quotes from the textbox `Format-specific options:`..available under "export options"

If you use Query try..[MySQL - export to csv some columns with quotes and some without; OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235878/mysql-export-to-csv-some-columns-with-quotes-and-some-without-optionally-encl)